# i don't get to see the two way binding value after the first submit button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Am trying to add items from the input into the div with `id = items`.

It seems to work on the first submit click but fails afterwards.

I observed that the two way data binding seems to disappear after the first submit click.

HTML code:

```
    <form>
        <input type="text"name="item"
        [(ngModel)]="test.text"> 
        <br> 
        <p>{{test.text}}</p> <!--disappears after the first 
        button click-->

        <input type="submit" value="Add" 
        (click)="addItem()">
    </form>
    <div id="items" *ngFor="let goal of goals">
        <p>
          {{ goal.text }}
        </p>
        <p>
          {{ goal.num }}
        </p>

    </div>
```

In my components file, I am trying to push the user inputs into an array and loop through it with the `ngFor` syntax above but it returns empty after the first result.

```
goals = [];
test: any = {text: "ok", num: "789"};

addItem() {
    this.goals.push(this.test);
    this.test = '';
    this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
 }
```

Where could I be going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are resetting the value of this.test  to an empty string in your addItem function

Comment: Like i just guessed. I wish to clear the input field after collecting the values. Please how do i go about it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your addItem function just change this

```
addItem() {
 this.goals.push(this.test);
 this.test = '';
 this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
}
```

to

```
addItem() {
 this.goals.push({...this.test});
 this.test.text = '';
 this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
}
```